# last version of Realm gives me problems

Tags: android, realm

I worked with realm for a while using version realm 80.0 fine whitout problem, but today I upagrade my realm's file to 80.3 but it gives me this problem :

```
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Primary key constraint broken. Value already exists: 0
            at io.realm.internal.Table.throwDuplicatePrimaryKeyException(Table.java:734)
            at io.realm.internal.Table.addEmptyRow(Table.java:380)
            at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:941)
            at io.realm.FieldRealmProxy.createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject(FieldRealmProxy.java:448)
            at io.realm.CartRealmProxy.createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject(CartRealmProxy.java:428)
            at io.realm.ApplicationRealmProxy.createOrUpdateUsingJsonObject(ApplicationRealmProxy.java:552)
```

the empty row must store the value null or what ? 
thank's

Comment: It seems to me that you're trying to update an object, and the new primary key that you want to use, it's already used by another object.

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace, it looks like you are using `createObject()` to create objects.

When working with primary keys, it is recommended to create the object as a standalone object first, set the primary key, and the use `copyToRealm()` to add/copy the object to your Realm (see also http://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#primary-keys).